# Linking Error after migrating IOS Project to Xcode 7.3.1 (Simulator and IPad)

Tags: ios, xcode7, linker-errors, ssziparchive

- I have an IOS-App SWIFT Project on Xcode 7.2 on my older yosemite machine, which works and builds fine.
- I have a new MAC running "El Capitan" with Xcode 7.3.1
- I have migrated my project to the new machine by just copying:
  the project folder, all external libraries and frameworks, imported provisioning profiles and keys
- My Project has no syntax errors anymore, after referencing all libraries to the new folder structure.

Now I build the project and I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSZipArchive", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.SSZipArchive in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know how to analyse this problem, thats why I am asking here.
Any help ?

I have added a small project for reproducing the error with Xcode 7.3.1 :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzTzuiIaUzqkeTNrQTZkdGxrUnM
Its a zipfile, which content can be unzipped onto the desktop. (SSArchiveTest is the rootfolder)

**UPDATE**

When trying to run on the IPAD I get the same error but referencing architecture arm64:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSZipArchive", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.SSZipArchive in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**UPDATE 2 What I have done so far**

What I have done so far:
- deleted derived data from xcode -> window -> project -> delete ...
- Updated SSZipArchive from GIT by downloading the newest source and replacing all stuff I already had in my running project.

**UPDATE 3 Small project added**

I have added a small project for reproducing the error with Xcode 7.3.1:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzTzuiIaUzqkeTNrQTZkdGxrUnM
Its a zipfile, which content can be unzipped onto the desktop. (SSArchiveTest is the rootfolder)

Comment: Link errors normally come down to one of the following issues: 1) the library/framework is not being found by the linker (see *Library Search Paths* in *Build Settings*). 2) The library/framework doesn't support the CPU architecture required.  To see if that's the issue you need to find the library/framework and use the `file` command on it to see what architectures it supports and probably get a newer/better version of the library.

Comment: I am not aware of using a library. I am just using *.h and *.m files, which of one I am bridging to the swift project. Probably I am understanding something wrong ?

Comment: I had assumed you were using the SSZipArchive code from a library.  If you are directly adding the `.m` files then it's probably just an issue with the target membership of the source file(s).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the SSZipArchive in your project. If you used cocoapods to install it, update the podfile.

Open a terminal window, go into your project folder and run

```
pod update
```

Comment: I do not use cocoapads, but I have updated the newest sources from GIT. I downloaded the latest SSZipArchive from GIT and replaced the SSZipArchive.h and .m & all minizip files. Still I have the same issue. Any help ?

Comment: check your build settings. The architecture of the build must match that of the library you are linking with.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.
Simpl adding the zlib.tbd in linking libraries solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The solution was to add all the *.c files (from the minizip and aes folders) to Targets --> Build Phases --> Compile Sources.